# Should i use Pycharm's VCS?

Tags: git, github, version-control, pycharm

I tried Github, Git and Pycharm's VCS. And if you ask me, they basically do the same things? So my questions are:

1.Should i use pycharm's VCS? Or maybe stick to other programs?
2.Any pros, cons using Pycharm's VCS?
3.Any real difference between Github, git and pycharm VCS Systems?

Answer (score 2):

what is pycharm vcs? I suspect it's the Git integration on the IDE

[Git](https://git-scm.com/) is a version control system

[GitHub](https://github.com/) is a cloud service to host a git repository

Pycharm VCS is an alternative to use git on command line. There are others like Atlassian SourceTree, Github Desktop, and so on.

I prefer to use the command line as it is more powerful, and I always know what I'm doing (also, in a remote server I can have no UI). It is also possible to configure aliases and make it really easy to do more complex commands

Answer (score 1):

Currently I am using PyCharm for python development, integrated with iPython Notebook inside PyCharm. Under the enviroment I can easily run my notebooks as well as to work on multiple projects on my Mac.

To add VCS to my program development I am looking into either using the PyCharm's integrated Git, or using command line Git. Based on my reading of PyCharm's help on the use of integrated Git, seems to me that if you are used to the command line Git, then it maybe better to use command line Git instead.

GitHub is a cloud site where you can store all of your files and vcs info for a team of developers to work together on projects, or sharing your works with others.

Wish the comments maybe helpful.